# Allow anonymouos access to healthcheck endpoint when authentication fallback policy is set in ASP.NET Core 3

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-3.0

asp.net core 3 allows to set **FallbackPolicy** to make the endpoints secure by default:

```cs
            services.AddAuthorization(options =>
            {
                options.FallbackPolicy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
                    .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                    .Build();
            });
```

It is a great feature, but I have a **HealthCheck** endpoint too, that requires Authorization now.

```cs
            services.AddHealthChecks();
            [...]
            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints => {
                endpoints.MapHealthChecks("/health");
                endpoints.MapControllers();
            });
```

How do I allow anonymous access to the HealthCheck endpoint (NO authentication or authorization)?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

I ran into exactly the same issue so I hope this helps as a more satisfactory way of achieving:

```
        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapDefaultControllerRoute().RequireAuthorization();

            endpoints.MapHealthChecks("/health").WithMetadata(new AllowAnonymousAttribute());

        });
```

Comment: Appears to be the better anwser, as the point of these changes seems to be to reduce the significance of ordering of the calls during startup.

Answer (score 48):

Starting with .NET 5 there is a [new](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/pull/21909) clearer method for this - `AllowAnonymous()`

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapHealthChecks("/health").AllowAnonymous();
    });
```

Comment: Can be used directly, without `UseEndpoint` ilike`app.MapHealthChecks("/health-check").AllowAnonymous();`

Comment: @Serg.ID, thanks! The WebApplication class returned by WebApplicationBuilder.Build() actually implements IEndpointRouteBuilder, too! So precisely the same [MapHealthChecks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.builder.healthcheckendpointroutebuilderextensions.maphealthchecks?view=aspnetcore-6.0) implementation is used.

Comment: [AllowAnonymous docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.builder.authorizationendpointconventionbuilderextensions.allowanonymous?view=aspnetcore-6.0)

Comment: That worked for me. I had to add app.UseRouting(); before because I was having an error ("InvalidOperationException: EndpointRoutingMiddleware matches endpoints setup by EndpointMiddleware and so must be added to the request execution pipeline before EndpointMiddleware. Please add EndpointRoutingMiddleware by calling 'IApplicationBuilder.UseRouting'").

Answer (score 21):

You could invoke the HealthCheckMiddleware before using the AuthenticationMiddleware:

```cs
app.Map("/health",appbuilder =>{
    appbuilder.UseMiddleware<HealthCheckMiddleware>();
});
// or 
// app.UseHealthChecks("/health");


app.UseRouting();
// make sure the authentication middleware runs after the health check middleware
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
        name: "default",
        pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
});
```

Comment: This worked for me! 

I also needed to specify HealthCheckOptions, this can be done by creating an object healthCheckOptions and passing it so: 
```appbuilder.UseMiddleware<HealthCheckMiddleware>(Options.Create(healthCheckOptions));```
Another hint: In `ConfigureServices` method I also put ```AddHealthChecks``` call before configuring any authorization.

Comment: BTW, I had the same problem with swagger/OpenApi endpoint. I needed to move `UseOpenApi` and `UseSwaggerUi3` methods before the `UseAuthentication` in `Configure` so the endpoint does not need authentication to render the ui.

Comment: @wxt Actually, the order of services doesn't matter, which is different from middlewares :)

Comment: I think this a more appropriate answer as it uses the existing Middleware functionality of using the stuff in correct order..