# How to configure JWT for ASP.NET API containing public razor pages and health checks

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, jwt, razor-pages

I have a hard time configuring the API authentication and authorization. There is definitely something I do not understand. Ideas appreciated.

I have NET Core 3.1 API. It contains Razor Pages (documentation and Swagger UI).
There is no sign-in endpoint. The token is validated using the secret signing key.

Requirements:

1. Use JWT
2. Make all endpoints protected by default.
3. Razor pages are public.
4. Enable anonymous access to health checks.
5. Enable anonymous access to several endpoints.
6. Support roles.

I am not sure how to combine all the settings to make it work properly.
I've implemented a custom authentication handler.
I've tried many combinations, add/removing parts of the config.

The main problem is the handler is called every time (AllowAnonymous attribute is ignored) or I'm getting 401 instead of 403.

Playing with:

```cs
// in controllers
[Authorize(Roles="Role")]
[AllowAnonymous]

// in configure services
services.AddRazorPages(options => options.Conventions.AllowAnonymousToFolder("/"));

services
    .AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddScheme<JwtBearerOptions, JwtBearerAuthenticationHandler>(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options => { });

services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    // expected to add the default schema for the [Authorize] attribute (so I do not need to write it explicitly)
    options.DefaultPolicy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
               .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
               .Build();
    // tried to resolve the health checks call the authentication handler
    options.AddPolicy("PublicPolicy", new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
               .RequireAssertion(_ => true)
               .Build());
});

// in configure
app.UseAuthentication(); // will cause all actions like decoreted with [Authorize]
app.UseAuthorization();

app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapRazorPages().RequireAuthorization(SecurityRegistration.PublicPolicyName);

    // map health checks
    endpoints.MapApiHealthChecks("/health")
        .RequireAuthorization("PublicPolicy");
}
```

I have implemented a custom authentication handler. Later on, I refactored it and inherited the JwtBearerHandler.

```cs
public class JwtBearerAuthenticationHandler: JwtBearerHandler
{
    protected override async Task<AuthenticateResult> HandleAuthenticateAsync() 
    {
    }
}
```

Why not using the `AddJwtBearer()`? I am generating/validating the tokes and I need to implement the OptionsMonitor pattern (reading the security settings from JSON, namely signing key, issuer, audience and expiration).

I expected that when I decorate a controller or an action with `[AllowAnonymous]` attribute, the handler will not be invoked. But it is called every time.

When I remove the `UseAuthentication()` I am getting issues with the default authentication schema and I'm getting 401 instead of 403.

I've also tried to add/remove the authorize attribute to controllers using a filter with/without a policy parameter.
`configure.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter());`

Comment: Do you mean you want to enable anonymous for healthcheck and razor pages? If this is you requirement, I suggest you could try to refer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60262492/7609093).

Comment: @BrandoZhang Thanks for the link. I guess the ```endpoints.MapRazorPages().WithMetadata(new AllowAnonymousAttribute());``` and ```services.AddRazorPages(options => options.Conventions.AllowAnonymousToFolder("/"));``` result in the same things, don't they? I might missunderstood the concept of Authentication Handler. I didn't expect it will be called even for the anonymous endpoints.